# Java 'for loop' variables declared in the parameter list

Tags: java, for-loop

How do I write a 'for' loop that starts counting from the given 'start' number? Without the first statement in the loop, the code will result in an error.  Writing 'start = 0;' starts the counting from 0. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
    end--;
    System.out.print(start);
}
```

Although in actuality if you want your code to work you have to do:

```
for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
    System.out.print(start);
}
```

Comment: the second ones works! didnt think of that, thank you!

Comment: it allows me to do so after 10 mins but will do :)

Comment: @MAnn :P Glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You can leave the initial statement blank and just put a semicolon.

```
for(; start <= end; start++)
```